# How to draw the region $|z|=Arg(z)$ in complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

How to draw the region $|z|=Arg(z)$ in complex number?
Well, in this moment if a take $z=x+iy$ then i have the relation $\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}= \arctan \frac{y}{x} + 2\pi k$, but in both side depends of $x,y$, what or how i need to continued?

Other way is maybe put $z=re^{i\theta}$ implies $r= \theta$ but this is one line with slope 1 on the plane $r,\theta$. This is the answer?

Please, somebody can help me?

Comment: Your second approach "$r=\theta$" is the easiest. Yes, that's a line with slope $1$ on the "$r,\theta$ plane", but nobody ever draws the $r,\theta$ plane, they always draw the $x,y$ plane.

you want the set of points where the distance away from the origin equals the angle from the $x$ axis. That's going to be a spiral of some kind. Plot a few points, and join them together.

Comment: Thank you so much, i can´t see the spiral, please can you tell me more?

Comment: [Perhaps this will help](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zyvhxwn6t5).

Comment: Note that $\theta$ can not be negative.

Comment: Perfect, thanks anyone!